# How can i add a search input field in my dropdown?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css

I'm trying to do a drop-down with all of my "Stations". I have managed to get all my data from the database into my drop-down, but i would like to add a search field into my drop-down, to make it easier for the user to search for the wanted "Station".
Here is how my drop-down looks for the moment:

```
<div>
    <select class="form-control">
        <option>--Select--</option>       
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.ListOfDropdown)
        {
            <option value="@item.Id">@item.Name</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>
```

And here is how i would like to look my drop down ( just an example found on w3school ):

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Bootstrap</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Angular</a></li>
    </ul>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".dropdown-menu li").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Any ideea if i can integrate this with my existing dropdown?

Comment: You can try using [jQueryUi autocomplete](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Comment: You can use select2 bootstrap library, look at this example: https://select2.github.io/select2-bootstrap-theme/4.0.3.html

Comment: Have you checked the [whole example on w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_dropdown.asp)? There´s a simple example for a dropdown with search, consisting of 3 steps.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".dropdown-menu li").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search.."> @foreach (var item in ViewBag.ListOfDropdown) {
    <li><a href="#">@item.Name</a></li>
    }
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to disagree slightly with other answers. You don't need that many things to make it work. **All you need is a line or two of js**. Since you're using jquery especially it's easy to just let razor do its thing (as in create html) and once the document is ready, prepend the input as you would type it if it was plain html.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $(".dropdown-menu").prepend("<input class='form-control' id='myInput' type='text' placeholder='Search..'>")
})
```

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">

  <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bootstrap</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Angular</a></li>
</ul>
```

And the js in ES5:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".dropdown-menu").prepend("<input class='form-control' id='myInput' type='text' placeholder='Search..'>")
})
```

Or in your case:

ES5:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".form-control").prepend("<input class='form-control' id='myInput' type='text' placeholder='Search..'>")
})
```

Fat arrow:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  $(".form-control").prepend("<input class='form-control' id='myInput' type='text' placeholder='Search..'>")
})
```

Comment: i know it may sound really dumb...but for some reason the javascript doesn't get the job done, not even if i inserted it between `<script>` tags...

Comment: Which one? If fat arrow doesn't work it's because it's ES6. Try the ES5 one. If it doesn't work, what's the error? Also, the example from w3schools is using jquery. Are you using jquery?

Comment: I managed to make it work *somehow*, but if i set the class of the `<ul>` as `dropdown-menu` for some reason the dropdown is not even displayed and if i set the class to `form-control` (mine) i get a list of items, but the input box gets send behind the list (the list overlaps the text box)

Comment: if the dropdown-menu is not displayed then maybe its css is set to display: none? I can't know your css. But at least my answer works.

Comment: @secene if you found the answer, don't forget to accept it as an answer, so other users that will bump into your question will be able to figure it out.

Answer (score -1):

You can use one of the many available libraries for that. Try using "Selectpicker".

Example: 
Consider you have a dropdown like this

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap- select@1.13.9/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
</head>

<select name="stations" id="stations">
     <option>Station 1</option>
     <option>Station 2</option>
     <option>Station 3</option>
</select>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#stations").selectpicker();
});
</script>
```

Link: https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/

Comment: Please add code to your answer. Link-only answers are deleted, not only because of their short length and lack of explanation, but also because links break and become not useful to future users